# Python -- generator interspersing value between iterator -- am I doing this correctly?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I have this function I made:

```
def iter_intersperse(iterOver, injectItem, startWithIter = True):
    for item in iterOver:
        sendItem = (item, injectItem) if startWithIter else (injectItem, item)
        yield sendItem
```

to intersperse an item between items in a generator.  It's for some wxpython AddMany calls and I want to add a spacer between each panel in a large dictionary (all the spacers are the same size).  It works, but seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do even though it is so small.

I've gone through a few options I could think of -- creating a list of the spacers that is the same length as the dictionary of panels and zipping them, that seemed like even more overkill.  I thought I could maybe do a toggle generator with set() True or False, etc, but I couldn't think of how to make it work.  I was told awhile back that if you are ever making an function that iterates, you're probably not thinking of some itertool that already does it.  I know cycle does it, but it takes just as much code as my function above.

For reference, I thought to just make a comprehension, but AddMany takes a list of tuples, and so I would have to convert from a list or dict -- that also seemed like overkill.

Can you think of a more elegant way?  Or, if not, is the code above as efficient as it could be?

Comment: What does the spacer accomplish (other than visual space)?

Comment: @g.d.d.c - Just visual space.

Comment: Should this thing be yielding `(item, injectItem)` tuples, or should it alternate between yielding `item`s from `iterOver` and yielding `injectItem`?

Comment: Yes, it should alternate.  The above sends back tuples because it was the lowest footprint way I could think of -- on the other end I just add the returns together into a long tuple.  In the end it should look like (item1, inject, item2, inject, item3, inject, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `zip` with `itertools.repeat`. Probably this is simple enough to do inline (where you'll know the order, presumably), but if you want it in a function, you can do that too:

```
def iter_intersperse(iterOver, injectItem, startWithIter = True):
    if startWithIter:
        return zip(iterOver, itertools.repeat(injectItem))
    return zip(itertools.repeat(injectItem), iterOver)
```

If you're using Python 2, and don't want the `list` that `zip` returns, use `itertools.izip` instead.

Edit: As it seems you want alternation, rather than tuples, try this generator function instead:

```
def iter_intersperse(iterOver, injectItem, startWithIter=True):
    if startWithIter:
        try:
            yield next(iterOver)
        except Stopiteration:
            return

    for item in iterOver:
        yield injectItem
        yield item
```

This doesn't yeild a last copy of `injectItem` at the end if `startWithIter` is `True`. If you want that, add `if not startWithIter: yield injectItem` at the end of the function. You could also consider adding a `stopWithIter` parameter too, if the choice of whether or not you want a trailing padding value isn't correlated to whether or not you want a leading pad value.

In all current and past versions of Python, you can let the `StopIteration` exception that might be raised by `next` (if the iterator is empty) bubble up to the caller. After [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) goes into effect (in 3.5 and 3.6 if you request it with `from __future__ import generator_stop`, in 3.7 for everyone), however, a "leaking" `StopIteration` will be transformed into a `RuntimeError`. So, to avoid issues in the future, I use a `try`/`except` pair to `return` from the generator (which will raise a new `StopIteration` exception in the outer scope).

Comment: Since the OP has clarified that this is supposed to alternate, not yield tuples, I suggest applying `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. At this point, the lines are getting long enough that it may be worth dropping the `itertools` prefix with a few `from` imports, or separating out the logic for interleaving two iterators into its own function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with an empty list and fillvalue for this.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for x, y in zip_longest([], [1, 2, 3], fillvalue='inject'):
    print(x, y)

'inject' 1
'inject' 2
'inject' 3
```

And if you want to flatten the result, use chain

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

def iter_intersperse(iterOver, injectitem, startWithIter=True):
    args = [[], iterOver] if startWithIter else [iterOver, []]
    return chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=injectitem))
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the alternation you want isn't hard:

```
def iter_intersperse(iterOver, injectItem, startWithIter = True):
    for item in iterOver:
        sendItem = (item, injectItem) if startWithIter else (injectItem, item)
        for thing in sendItem:
            yield thing
```

This version is  bit cleaner, and easier to modify

```
def iter_intersperse(iterOver, injectItem, startWithIter = True):
    # Controls whether we want to start with injection
    inject = not startWithIter 
    for item in iterOver:
        if inject:
            yield injectItem
        yield item
        inject = True
    # If we want to end with an injection
    if startWithIter:
        yield injectItem
```